# loop animate javascript, SetInterval works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I am using JavaScript to try to animate a `div`. For some reason, my `div` doesn't keep going right `400px` in a loop every 2 seconds, it only moves once.

**The JavaScript:**

```
<script>
    function animate(name,dist,time) {
        $(name).animate({left:dist},time);
    }
    $(function() {
        setInterval(animate('.box1',400,800),2000);
    });
</script>
```

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="box1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function animate(name,dist,time) {
    $(name).animate({left:dist},time);
}
$(function() {
    setInterval(
        function() {
            animate('.box1',"+=400",800)
        },
        2000
    );
});
```

You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/CliffBurton/k03cyup1/ (I used `50px` just for test)

The jQuery `animate()` function's properties can be relative.

> If a value is supplied with a leading `+=` or `-=` sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property.

And here you can find the [jQuery `animate()` function reference](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    animate('.box1',400,800);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: It still plays it one... i used "relative" position for my box